# InvalidCiphertextException when calling kms.decrypt with S3 metadata

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-kms

I can add a client-side encrypted file via the Java SDK, and I can fetch the file too. I'm now trying to access it with boto3. (I know boto3 doesn't have support for this, but s3-wrapper does. This concerns boto3, though).

I'm getting the s3 metadata and then calling kms.decrypt like this:

```
object_info = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
metadata = object_info['Metadata'] # metadata is a dict with lots of x-amz-key, x-amz-iv, etc
ekey = kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=metadata,EncryptionContext=metadata)

# fails with:
# ParamValidationError:
# Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter CiphertextBlob, value: .. type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object`
```

So, what if I should be passing in the key as the CiphertextBlob?

```
# this key looks like 'CiAlgoyM4k...
ekey = kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=metadata['x-amz-key-v2'],EncryptionContext=metadata)

# fails with:
# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidCiphertextException) when calling the Decrypt operation: None
```

Then I tried passing in a base64'd key:

```
# this key looks like b'\n %\x82\x8c\x8c\xe2ML...
cblob = base64.b64decode(metadata['x-amz-key-v2'])
ekey = kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=cblob,EncryptionContext=metadata)

# (still) fails with:
# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidCiphertextException) when calling the Decrypt operation: None
```

I then tried passing in the s3 contents as the blob.

```
full_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
ekey = kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=full_object['Body'].read(),EncryptionContext=metadata)

# Still fails with:
# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidCiphertextException) when calling the Decrypt operation: None
```

So, I guess my question is, what is a proper CiphertextBlob from the S3 metadata? Since I'm placing it with the Java SDK's [EncryptedPutObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/EncryptedPutObjectRequest.html) and [AmazonS3EncryptionClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3EncryptionClient.html), which abstracts it away, I don't know what that blob should look like.

### related links

- stackoverflow: [client-side decryption in ruby; does not use KMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784535/how-to-decrypt-aws-ruby-client-side-encryption-in-python)
- boto3 github issues: [the start of kms decryption in boto3 for s3; does not work, perhaps because this is a "v2" key?](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/38#issuecomment-163298874)

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, I'm almost sure you encrypted the file using envelope encryption, and not a customer master key (`# metadata is a dict with lots of x-amz-key, x-amz-iv, etc`). Another issue is that you are passing an encryption context, but always making it be the entire dictionary. Is this your intention?

So, my suggestions are:

1. Make sure you call `kms.decrypt` on your envelope key, and then actually decrypt the data with the decrypted key (assuming my comment above is correct).
2. Double-check you're passing what you want on your encryption context.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use *EncryptionContext* option, first add the "Encryption Context" option when **encrypting**.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.encrypt